# Can't get value in a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSString *stringImageURL = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"artworkUrl100"];
```

The last line is the issue. I can get the array perfectly fine but the value of `stringImageURL` is nil. How do I correctly retrieve the key highlighted below?

[image: The NSDictionary value I want to use]

Comment: So you found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004087/iphone-app-how-to-get-app-icon-from-app-id/14004218#14004218)... ;-)

Comment: Actually no lmao. @H2CO3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your jsonArray is not an array, but a dictionary.

Second, looks like you have a dictionary with an array of dictionaries, so it would be:

```
NSArray *resultsArray = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *resultDict = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *stringImageURL = [resultDict valueForKey:@"artworkUrl100"];
```

Comment: recommend using "objectForKey" instead of "valueForKey".  The former is a method of NSDictionary, while the latter is part of KVO for NSObjects.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just cut and paste his code without noticing that.

Comment: `valueForKey` will still work, NSDictionary overrides this, and will call `objectForKey` if the key doesn't begin with `"@"`

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *stringImageURL = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"artworkUrl100"];
```

Should be

```
NSString *stringImageURL = [[[jsonArray valueForKey:@"result"]
                                      objectAtIndex:0]
                                        valueForKey:@"artworkUrl100"];
```

Or, more concisely

```
NSString *stringImageURL = jsonArray[@"result"][0][@"artworkUrl100"];
```

### Why?

The data was nested 2 levels deeper than you thought, the dictionary value you were after was contained within an array, in another dictionary, under the key `result`.

Comment: Even after narrowing it down 2 keys it appears the string still has an unnamed key in it.

Comment: Actually the results object is an array of dictionaries. See the [0] entry below results value.

Comment: Just had to just objectAtIndex. Thanks!

Comment: @WDUK don't worry your answer was helpful too :)